# Javascript regexp (match after ":" symbol)

Tags: javascript, regex

How to get all text following the symbol "`:`"?

I have tried:

```
'prop:bool*'.match(/:(.[a-z0-9]+)/ig)
```

But it returns `[":bool"]` not `["bool"]`.

**Update:**

I need to use this inside the following expression:

```
'prop:bool*'.match(/^[a-z0-9]+|:.[a-z0-9]+|\*/ig);
```

So that the result becomes:

```
["prop", "bool", "*"]
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can not use capture groups?

Comment: @trognanders I need to get three results `prop`, `bool`, `*`

Comment: because I also need to match `'prop:bool'.match(/^([a-z0-9]+):([a-z0-9]+)(\*)$/i)` and get `prop` and `bool`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think there is some subtle misunderstanding here because they really do not want to use capture groups even though they are the kind of obvious solution to the very simple example. It looks a lot like an attempt at a lexer which would obviously need to obtain one token per match.

Comment: Could you instead treat `:` and `*` as separate tokens and analyze them at a higher leve by looking at the tokens instead? `/\*|:|[a-z0-9]+/`

Comment: In case you are accidentally writing a compiler, this might be an excellent and free book to look through: http://hjemmesider.diku.dk/~torbenm/Basics/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this by performing a positive [lookbehind](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/the-complicated-syntax-of-lookaheads-in-javascript-regular-expressions/) action.

`'prop:bool*'.match(/^[a-z0-9]+|(?<=:).[a-z0-9]+|\*/ig)`

The positive lookbehind is the `(?<=:)` part of the regex and will here state a rule of `must follow ':'`.

The result should here be `["prop", "bool", "*"]`.

**Edit:**

Original requirements were somewhat modified by original poster to return three groups of answers. My original code, returning one answer, was the following:
`'prop:bool*'.match(/(?<=:).[a-z0-9]+/ig)`

Comment: and thanks for a link. that's what I need, three result `prop`, `bool`, `*` in complex regexp
`'prop:bool*'.match(/^[a-z0-9]+|(?<=:).[a-z0-9]+|\*/ig)`

Comment: Glad i could help! Please consider marking my answer as accepted if you feel it was a viable solution to your problem.
I have no idea why my answer has been down voted by someone though.

Comment: thanks a lot I'll use that in that open source project https://github.com/99xt/react-scaffolder/

Answer (score 1):

This is not a pure regex solution since it takes advantage of the String Object with its substring() method, as follows:

```js
var str = 'prop:bool*';
var match = str.match(/:(.[a-z0-9]+)/ig).pop().substring(1,str.length);
console.log(match);
```

When the match is successful, an array of one element will hold the value `:bool`.  That result just needs to have the `bool` portion extracted. So, the element uses its pop() method to return the string value.  The string in turn uses its substring() method to bypass the ':' and to extract the desired portion, namely `bool`.

```js
var [a,b,c] = 'prop:bool*'.match(/^([a-z0-9]+)|:(.[a-z0-9]+)|(\*)/ig);

console.log(a,b.substring(1,b.length),c);
```

To return three groups of data, the code uses capture groups and trims off the colon by using the substring() method of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

`'prop:bool*'.match(/:(.[a-z0-9]+)/)[1]`

Comment: No I actually need that inside that expression /^[a-z0-9]+|:.[a-z0-9]+|\*/ig

Answer (score 0):

If your entire string is of the form you show, you could just use a regex with capture groups to get each piece:

```js
console.log('prop:bool*'.match(/^([a-z0-9]+):(.[a-z0-9]+)(\*)/i).slice(1));
```